# How to give a click function for center | focus image in roudabout carousel?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, carousel

I am trying to give click function to focus image (center image) in jQuery round about carousel .

http://fredhq.com/projects/roundabout/demos/images in this url I need click function which should go to other web page.
I need this function only for center(focus) image not for other child images . For other image it should come in focus and then I need click even to happen.

For example :

On click of the center or focus image I need to go to (open new window) google.com

Questions :

1. Is there any way to call a onclick event for focus image ?
2. If its not possible through roundabout carousel is there any other carousel which supports this.
3. http://fredhq.com/projects/roundabout  Is there any API I can use for this on click event?

Answer (score 2):

You can take advantage of the [`focus`](http://fredhq.com/projects/roundabout#focus) event which is fired by the plugin:

```
$('li').bind('focus', function(e){ console.log(e.target); })
```

Where `li` are the children nodes of the HTML for the roundabout and `e.target` will be the DOM element which is currently in focus/front-and-center of the carousel.

### Update

I realized that **just** the `focus` event isn't quite all that you need, since you are looking to do something when the focused element is **clicked**.  For this case, you can use jQuery's [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method or [`delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) (depending on what version of jQuery you are using)

```
// jQuery >= 1.7
$('ul').on('click', '.roundabout-in-focus', function(e) { console.log(this); });

// jQuery >= 1.4.2
$('ul').delegate('.roundabout-in-focus', 'click', function(e){ console.log(this); })
```

This uses [event delegation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687296/what-is-dom-event-delegation) to attach a listener to the parent `ul` node which will only fire when the element which was clicked has the class `roundabout-in-focus` which it looks like the roundabout plugin gives the focused class by default, thought I'm not 100% sure that is guaranteed to always be the case.  In the callback, `this` refers to the `li` element which was clicked.

Comment: Thanks you for your prompt reply.  I am new to jquery . Can let me know how can I give click for focus or center image with this bind function.